# Why app overriding after installing in android?

Tags: flutter

I build an app using flutter. For example name is `ForSaudi`. I wanted to copy the same app and which name should be `ForJordon`.

So `ForSaudi` is already installed in my mobile. Everything is good. Now I changed the name to `ForJordon` from `AndroidManifest.xml` file. After changing name and launcher icon, I installed the app into mobile, which is actually replaced with my previous app. It should not be replaced. Can someone guide me how can I do that? I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Only changing name doesn't create new package. You also need to make changes in build.gradle and in your MainActivity.kt.

If you want a simple solution. Directly use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name)

and run this command

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```